# Possibility to receive the Speech Recognition Confidence score in the Webhook Request when using the Phone Gateway or Actions-On-Google

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

We are using the Telephony Gateway with our Dialogflow application. In order to build a rich conversational experience, we would like to be able to receive the "Speech Recognition Confidence score" of the user utterance in the fulfillment in order to be able to add confirmation steps when needed.

Even when testing using the Telephony Gateway we don't seem to be able to access this data.

The documentation of the Webhook Request definitions for Dialogflow or Actions-On-Google do not specify this metric:

- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#webhook_request
- https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhook/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest

Any idea or suggestions on how to get to get this data (Speech Recognition score) while in the fulfillment?

thanks,

Francois

Comment: Is there somewhere where you found this field mentioned?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/DetectIntentResponse

The API's documentation for `DetectIntentResponse` specifies the field `speechRecognitionConfidence` in the `QueryResult` portion.


Except that the DetectIntentResponse is received after query has been processed while we are looking to make use of it during the fulfillment.

Comment: Your project is using v2beta1?